# Combine python sublists whose second element is the same and return the sum and second element

Tags: python

How can I return a single list from sublists where the sublists second element is the same. e.g

given a list

```
a = [
[1442, '17-10-17'],
[5437, '19-11-17'],
[5778, '27-11-17'],
[5901, '27-11-17'],
[5875, '27-11-17'],
[5947, '28-11-17']
    ]
```

it should return

```
[
[1442, '17-10-17'],
[5437, '19-11-17'],
[a[2][0] + a[3][0] + a[4][0], '27-11-17'],
[5947, '28-11-17']
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I had forgot to add some other details in that list, so what will the solution look like  if this is the input 

`a = [
[1442, '17-10-17', 'a'],
[5437, '19-11-17', 'b'],
[5778, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5901, '27-11-17,  'c'],
[5875, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5947, '28-11-17', 'd']
    ]`

return a single list from sublists where the sublists second and third element is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want a list but you can do this with a dictionary - which i personally believe is a nicer way of doing it.

## **Original Question Answer**

Let's look at your example variable:

```
a = [
[1442, '17-10-17'],
[5437, '19-11-17'],
[5778, '27-11-17'],
[5901, '27-11-17'],
[5875, '27-11-17'],
[5947, '28-11-17']
 ]
```

We then run it through

```
dates = {}
for item in zip([item[0] for item in a], [item[1] for item in a]):
    val, date = item
    try:
        dates[date].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        dates[date]  = [val]
```

This will return:

```
{'17-10-17': [1442], '19-11-17': [5437], '27-11-17': [5778, 5901, 5875], '28-11-17': [5947]}
```

To sum these arrays and keep the dictionary format:

```
for key, value in dates.items():
    dates[key] = [sum(value)]
```

If you wish to convert this back into a list:

```
for key, value in dates.items():
    dates_list.append([sum(value), key])
```

Now `dates_list = [[1442, '17-10-17'], [5437, '19-11-17'], [17554, '27-11-17'], [5947, '28-11-17']]`

---

## **Updated Question Answer**

if the array looks like this:

```
a = [
[1442, '17-10-17', 'a'],
[5437, '19-11-17', 'b'],
[5778, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5901, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5875, '27-11-17', 'd'],
[5947, '28-11-17', 'd']
 ]
```

Then we run:

```
a = [[n[0], [n[2], n[1]]] for n in a]
```

Now an edited version of the main code:

```
dates = {}
for item in zip([item[0] for item in a], [item[1] for item in a]):
    val, date = item
    try:
        dates[tuple(date)].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        dates[tuple(date)]  = [val]
```

Then convert it back to the format you wanted originally:

```
dates_list = []
for key, value in dates.items():
    dates_list.append([sum(value), *key])
```

The full code is:

```
a = [
[1442, '17-10-17', 'a'],
[5437, '19-11-17', 'b'],
[5778, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5901, '27-11-17', 'c'],
[5875, '27-11-17', 'd'],
[5947, '28-11-17', 'd']
 ]

a = [[n[0], [n[2], n[1]]] for n in a]


dates = {}
print(list(zip([item[0] for item in a], [item[1] for item in a])))

for item in zip([item[0] for item in a], [item[1] for item in a]):
    val, date = item
    try:
        dates[tuple(date)].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        dates[tuple(date)]  = [val]
    print('val=',val , 'date=', date)
print(dates)

dates_list = []
for key, value in dates.items():
    dates_list.append([sum(value), *key])
    print('key=',key,'value=',value)
print(dates_list)
```

Comment: True , but  I had forgot to add some other details in that list, so what will the solution look like if this is the input `a = [ [1442, '17-10-17', 'a'], [5437, '19-11-17', 'b'], [5778, '27-11-17', 'c'], [5901, '27-11-17, 'c'], [5875, '27-11-17', 'c'], [5947, '28-11-17', 'd'] ]`

Comment: Sorry, you didn't specify that within your question - perhaps you should edit your question to include that...

Comment: Correct, I hadn't specified that, now I have.

Comment: I've added to the bottom a way of doing it with your data set. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in a:
    d_dict[v] += k

[[v,k] for k,v in d_dict.items()]
```

Output:

```
[[1442, '17-10-17'],
 [5437, '19-11-17'],
 [17554, '27-11-17'],
 [5947, '28-11-17']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the required transformations:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

b = OrderedDict()
for x, y in a:
    b.setdefault(y, 0)  #This will ensure every new key is initialised with zero
    b[y] += x           #This will add the corresponding value to zero or previous sum

a = [[y, x] for x, y in b.items()]
```

The output will be:

```
[[1442, '17-10-17'],
 [5437, '19-11-17'],
 [17554, '27-11-17'],
 [5947, '28-11-17']]
```